# GraalVM and JNA dependency

Tags: java, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I can not start my application with JNA dependencies. Compilation of the app was ok, but on starting/runtime
the JNA library can not be found. From the IDE - no problem but not from the native-compiled version.
Did I forget something for loading resources? How can I configure graalvm to make them find the dependency? I am using the gradle-plugin: `org.graalvm.buildtools.native`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native library (com/sun/jna/win32-x86-64/jnidispatch.dll) not found in resource path ()
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:1059)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:1015)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:221)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLong.<clinit>(NativeLong.java:35)
    at java.base@17.0.8/java.lang.Class.ensureInitialized(DynamicHub.java:579)
```

Comment: can you create a reproducer ? it will be easier to investigate with proper build gradle and code and all. also do not forget to put which commands do you use for creating the native binary

Answer (score 0):

Got it, it worked with the following combination:

- I used the Graal-Agent to generate metadata-files ([Tracing Agent](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/metadata/AutomaticMetadataCollection/))
- Added all of them to the gradle definition like this

  ```
   buildArgs.add("-H:JNIConfigurationFiles=${projectDir}/src/main/resources/conf/jni-config.json")
   buildArgs.add("-H:DynamicProxyConfigurationFiles=${projectDir}/src/main/resources/conf/proxy-config.json")
   buildArgs.add("-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=${projectDir}/src/main/resources/conf/reflect-config.json")
   buildArgs.add("-H:ResourceConfigurationFiles=${projectDir}/src/main/resources/conf/resource-config.json")
  ```
- added `buildArgs.add('-H:+JNI')`
- removed `buildArgs.add('--initialize-at-build-time')` (Don't know why this is required)